# How could spirit bomb kill Majin Buu?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

How could spirit bomb kill Majin Buu when Frieza wasn't much affected by it?

All of us know that Majin Buu was far stronger than Frieza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spirit bomb against Majin Buu was simply far more powerful than the one used against Frieza.
The strength of a spirit bomb depends on the amount of energy the user can gather.
During the fight against Frieza the energy comes from Namek and some nearby planets. At that point the population on Namek was quite decimated so there wasn't much energy from there.
Against Majin Buu the energy came from the strongly populated Earth, the Other World, New Namek and the rest of the surviving planets of the sector.

Source : Dragon Ball Wiki articles regarding the Spirit Bombs against [Frieza](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Large_Spirit_Bomb) and [Majin Buu](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Spirit_Bomb).

Comment: Even then, It was not enough. Buu pushed it back, And it was only when the Wish for Goku to get his energy back that caused it to work. As Vegeta said, SSJ3 Goku would have likely been able to beat Kid buu, As kid buu was one of the weakest, but most dangerous forms. The Spririt bomb origionally pushed Buu back a bit, but was repelled, then Goku at full power increased its size several fold, and Buu was obliterated.